# Zabbix: не собирает данные из Zabbix-proxy в закрытой сети

Tags: linux, сеть, centos, zabbix

Вставлять что-то в виде фрагментов кода не могу, потому что работаю через VMware Vsphere. Могу предоставить все необходимые скриншоты.

В общей сети развернут центральный общий сервер мониторинга Zabbix (**10.127.0.84/28**) В другой закрытой сети находится несколько важных серверов состояние которых нужно мониторить. В закрытой сети развернули прокси-Заббикс с двумя сетевыми интерфейсами (**10.127.61.52/28** - закрытая и **10.127.0.92/28** - открытая), который должен в пассивном режиме отдавать данные центральному.
Сервера пингуют друг дружку, но в логах Заббикс-прокси сыпятся такие ошибки:
[image: скриншот ошибки прокси]

В логах Заббикс-сервера сыпятся такие ошибки:
[image: скриншот ошибки сервера]

Перепечатал настройки zabbix_proxy.conf (то что изменял):

```
ProxyMode=1
Hostname=zbx.proxy.1
DBName=Zabbix
DBUser=Zabbix
DBPassword=********
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переразвернул прокси-Заббикс вместо версии 4.2 на версию 3.4 (такой же версии основной сервер-Заббикс). Также прописал сетевой маршрут от сервера-Заббикс в закрытую сеть к прокси-Заббиксу. Заббикс-сервер увидел прокси-Заббикс.

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ решением.